# What is the execution order for more than one AST transformation in the same compiler phase?

Tags: groovy

I have applied an AST transformation which is wrapping each method in `try...catch`.  I want to make sure this AST transformation is executed after other AST transformations.

If I'm applying more than one AST transformations to the same class in the same compiler phase, what is the execution order or priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution order of transforms running in the same phase is unspecified. The only safe way to guarantee that one transform runs after another is to apply it in a later phase.

There are chances that the ordering is, at least to some extent, deterministic (you'd have to check the compiler source code), but I wouldn't consider this a strong guarantee (i.e. it might change between Groovy versions).