# groovy local ASTTransformation execution order

Tags: groovy, annotations, metaprogramming, immutability, abstract-syntax-tree

I wrote my own local ASTTransformation for an annotation `@WithLogging` with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` where my ASTTransformation has `@GroovyASTTransformation(phase=CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)` as compile phase.
When I annotate my class, the ASTTransformation adds logging to all methods and constructors it can find in this class. This works fine so far.

Now I also annotate my class with e.g. `@Immutable` which creates constructors from the class fields. These are now not logged by my `@WithLogging` annotation.

It seems that `@Immutable`s transformation is executed after my `@Withlogging` transformation. It's hard to debug because e.g. println in my ASTTransformation-subclass does not work (however the methods are decorated fine).

Can someone bring some light into the dark? Is there something I have to consider when debugging these transformations?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722938/what-is-the-execution-order-for-more-than-one-ast-transformation-in-the-same-com.

Comment: Yes, that seems to answer my question, thanks!